# How do I return the result of a class-based view from another class-based view in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

When I submit a certain `CreateView`, I want to move on to create another object in another `CreateView`. However, when I try

```
def get_success_url(self):
    return FooView.as_view()(self.request, itempk = self.object.id)
```

I get

> ContentNotRenderedError: The response content must be rendered before
>   it can be accessed.

I also tried

```
def get_success_url(self):
    return render(FooView.as_view()(self.request, itempk = self.object.id))
```

which gives me

> AttributeError: 'TemplateResponse' object has no attribute 'META'

I'm fairly certain I'm just going about this the wrong way, and that I've done it correctly before, but I'm stumped. What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to call the view, you want to redirect the user to it. So just use the `redirect` function:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
...
return redirect('foo_view_name', kwargs={'itempk': self.object.id})
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're defining the `get_success_url`, I would say that you just need something like

```
def get_success_url(self):
    # assuming that your FooView urlconf was named "foo_view"
    return reverse('foo_view', kwargs={'itempk':self.object.id})
```

Cf. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/